# Connect Genymotion from Another VirtualBox machine with adb

Tags: adb, virtual-machine, virtualbox, genymotion

I am using VirtualBox on a Mac and was stuck from trying to connect my both guest OS ( Ubuntu and Genymotion Emulator) together with `adb`.
I could ping from Ubuntu to Genymotion's vm but cannot use `adb` command to connect them. 
I also try to use the command `adb connect genymotion_ip` to force the connection, but the the genymotion's vm is offline when checking with the command `adb devices`.

FYI, for my connection between them, I am using `NatNetwork` for both of them. Also tried with `bridge` but still faced the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use bridge network and connecting using the good ip address like the one shown in the post here [How to connect a socket to Genymotion device that is hosting a server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36392543/how-to-connect-a-socket-to-genymotion-device-that-is-hosting-a-server/36455929#36455929)?

Answer (score 1):

Topic is old, but as I encountered the same problem, here is the solution I found:

1. In Virtualbox interface, configure Genymotion VM to have 2 network adapters (one of type *NAT* for internet access, and one of type *Host private network*)
2. In Vitualbox interface, configure your other VM to have a network adapter of type *Host private network*
3. Start Genymotion, and get its ip address on the *Host private network* (use virtualbox interface, or in host's console `adb shell ifconfig`)
4. In your host's console execute `adb tcpip 5556`
5. Start your other VM, and in its console execute `adb connect
   <ip_of_genymotion>:5556`
6. then in the VM's console check that `adb devices` show device connected (and not offline)

Now your emulator should be connected to your VM through adb.

This worked for me with Virtualbox running on Windows10, with Genymotion and a Debian8 VM.