# How to connect from VirtualBox machine to Host windows through ADB?

Tags: android, adb

I'm using Android Studio 2021.1.1 in windows10 and Santoku in VirtualBox 6.13 and i want to connect through ADB tool from Santoku to the Android Emulator that is running in windows.

I have check the ip for the android emulator from adb tool in windows and i got the ip address for the emulator which is

> C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools>adb shell
> root@android:/ # ifconfig eth0
> eth0: ip 10.0.2.15 mask 255.255.255.0 flags [up broadcast running
> multicast]

And when i use `adb connect 10.0.2.15:5554` in vm it gives me

> unable to connect to device

after checked many solutions like these:

> [How to connect a socket to Genymotion device that is hosting a server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36392543/how-to-connect-a-socket-to-genymotion-device-that-is-hosting-a-server/36455929#36455929)
>
> [Connect Genymotion from Another VirtualBox machine with adb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36448459/connect-genymotion-from-another-virtualbox-machine-with-adb)

I have an idea about the problem that is i need to set the network adapter from NAT to bridge in Android Emulator  but I don't know how to set it up in SDK .

Comment: any solutions ?

Comment: Did you try enable Host-Only network in VirtualBox and use its IP?